# joint probability distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

The problem is:

I have two partially overlapping histograms of different shapes, each corresponding ultimately to a certain fraction, let's say one histogram represents the value 50% and the other 40%. Then I have point and its uncertainty located on top of the two histograms. Thus the uncertainty region covers parts of each histogram. Thus, I can calculate: the point corresponds to lets say 80% likelihood to the 50% histogram and to 30% likelihood to the 40% histogram. However, ultimately what I would like to know is the combination of the two, sth like: my point corresponds to a value of ~47% plus minues 15% (taking the values of the histograms).

This problem is somehow really difficult to explain and I am not sure if it can be solved, but some help would be just amazing! Thank you!